# Using a subset of functionality from a Library in C++

Tags: c++, linker, include

I am using [SNAP](http://snap.stanford.edu) library in one of my project. I have a `#include"Snap.h"` which gives me the entire library's functionality.
However, I am just using the k-core algorithm and the underlying graph DS.

There is a lot of extra DS+Algorithms provided by the library as discussed here:
http://snap.stanford.edu/snap/description.html

If I compile the entire project and link my code with this library, it seems I will end up with a lot of extra stuff? Also I need to have the entire project directory setup for including appropriate headers.

The situation seems quite generic to C++, is there a quick and easy way to compile a subset of this library with only the features I need ?

Comment: This would depend on how the library is linked (statically or dynamically) and the toolset you use.  Also. are you concerned about the build-time space necessary or the binaries that you'd distribute? Are you running into an actual problem? If so, what exactly?

Comment: Both in general. Along with the binary size, I am also hesitant to share my source code with the entire Snap library (for includes). Would like to know what should be done in such a scenario ( to get rid of the bloat)?

Comment: Looks like it's BSD licensed, which is very permissive with regards to what you do with the code. That said, legal questions are off topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: I am more interested into the technical aspects ( assuming there are no legal hindrances)

Answer (score 1):

1. if the library is dynamically linked and distributed as precompiled binary, you must live with that
2. if the library is statically linked you can use dead code elimination (if your compiler support it)
3. if you have sources, you can trim the library by removing unused code - ie. make your own library based on selected code only

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by using Boost and using the [bcp](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/tools/bcp/doc/html/index.html) utility to extract the relevant pieces of the library.